# Sharing photo with Whatsapp not working under Xcode 9.1 and iOS11

Tags: swift3

The below code used to work in Xcode8. But now it is not working in Xcode 9.1 with target iOS11. 
I did the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func ShareImages(_ sender: AnyObject)
{

    let urlWhats = "whatsapp://app"
    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
        if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {

            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {

                if let image = UIImage(named: "whatsappIcon") {
                    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
                        let tempFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai")
                        do {
                            try imageData.write(to: tempFile, options: .atomic)
                            self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: tempFile)
                            self.documentInteractionController.uti = "net.whatsapp.image"
                            self.documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)

                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {
                // Cannot open whatsapp
            }
        }
    }

}

// Added this in info.plist

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

Comment: What does *it is not working* mean? What happens when you run the code? I tried this and it seems that there are issues with `.wai` files. If I use `.jpg` instead of `.wai` everythings works as expected.

Comment: I tried both .jpg and .jpeg to replace .wai  and I could not get the UI Dialog for me to copy the image to whatsapp. My phone run ios 11.0.3 and the above app wrote in Xcode 9.1